# Method exists but java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method

Tags: java, android

I have 2 buttons in a layout. One works (contacts) the other (buy_coins) does not. My activity_main layout file and MainActivity.java files are as follows:

```
activity_main.xml

...
<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button2"
    android:background="@null"
    android:text="Contacts"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="contacts"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button3"
    android:background="@null"
    android:text="Purchase Coins"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="buy_coins"/>

MainActivity.java
...
    public void contacts(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Contacts.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void buy_coins(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, BuyCoins.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    }
```

When I click on button  I receive the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method buy_coins(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'Button3'

The activities are included in my AndroidManifest file.

Comment: what happens if you remove the underscore?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the setContentView in the BuyCoins activity was incorrect.